# htaccess redirect dynamic urls

Tags: .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a htaccess redirect, but it is not working as I want it to.
My current (working) htaccess redirects all html pages with 1 character to the index file as:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]).html$ index.php?letter=$1
```

So a.html gets redirected to index.php?letter=a
Now I need to redirect the page a.html?page=2 to index.php?letter=a&page=2
Basically I want to redirect the url, but leave the dynamic part intact.
All of the following return a 404:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]).html?page=([0-9]+) index.php?letter=$1&page=$2

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]).html?page=(.*) index.php?letter=$1&page=$2

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(.*)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]).html(.*) index.php?letter=$1&page=%1
```

I think I'm close, but I can't seem to get there :/ 
could anyone give me the last push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `RewriteRule` needs to be

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9])\.html$ index.php?letter=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Please, note that URL parameters are **not** available for matching within the `RewriteRule`. If you simply need to append an extra URL parameter you can do so along with the `[QSA]` flag which would take care of appending the original URL parameters for you.

Please, note that the dot before `html` needs to be escaped `\.` as well. The `[L]` makes sure that rewriting stops and no further rules (if any below) are applied.

Comment: great stuff, thanks! htaccess rewrites are hard...
Did not know about the escape for the dot, but it seems to be working fine without it.
just to be clear for others that might need to understand: the rewritecond is not necessary.

Comment: @bolvo, it works because `.` matches any character so even invalid paths like `/k9html` would get served.