# How to rewrite a url without variables to one containing variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm new to rewriting so I'm not even sure this is possible.

I have this URL: http://my.domain.com/index.php?CID=2

I want to type http://my.domain.com/meet-our-team and have the above page come up without showing the real url (index.php?CID=2).

This is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^meet-our-team$ index.php?CID=2 [NC,L]
```

This seems to redirect me to my home page. How can I do this simple rewrite?

Thank you,
Luke

Comment: this rule has no redirect. Try in a new browser. Are there more rules also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@syntrax - Thanks, I also found those and other similar posts but could not get much help from them due to the fact that I don't believe I'm using rewrite rules the way they are intended.

What I wanted to do was create any SEF url (e.g. **example.com/this-is-my-sef-page**) and have it point to a url that would normally be something like **example.com/index.php?catid=1$id=5**.

It looks as though all I can do is rewrite whats in the original url so I would need to use a method like this: http://moz.com/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls

That method doesn't create a clean enough sef url for me so my solution is to have a list of valid url redirects all point to my index.php page:

```
RewriteRule ^my-sef-url$ index.php
RewriteRule ^my-other-sef-url$ index.php
```

index.php checks the url against a sef mappings table and displays the appropriate page based on the sef mapping in the database. This is much easier than creating complex .htaccess rules and allows me a lot more flexibility on my sef urls.

Answer (score 0):

I found two things:

- RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$
  RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/content/page? [R=301,L]
- [htaccess redirect dynamic urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19224396/htaccess-redirect-dynamic-urls)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the URL correspondingly using mod_rewrite into .htaccess for example.

```
Desired URL = www.yoursite.com/index/users/add/



URL = www.yoursite.com/index.php?controller=users&option=add



.htaccess code :
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)/(.*)\.html index.php?controller=$1&option=$2 [QSA]
```

So you will get "user" and "add" value in GET method variables